# Rudin exercise 3.8 solution

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem** . if the sequence $\sum\limits_{}{a_{n}}$ converges and $b_{n}$ is a monotonic bounded sequence then $\sum\limits_{} {a_{n}b_{n}}$ converges.

**Solution**. Let's use the identity:
$\sum\limits_{n=p}^q {a_{n}b_{n}}$ = $\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}+s_{q}b_{q}-s_{p-1}b_{p}$, where $s_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {a_{n}}$. Then $|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}|<=|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}}|B$, where B is the difference of upper and lower bound of the sequence $b_{n}$. since $a_{n}$ is convergent we can make $|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}}|$ as small as we want and therefore we can make this $|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}|$ as small as we want like $x/3$. Then let's take the absolute value of another term of the right side of the identity. 
$|s_{q}b_{q}|<=|s_{q}||b_{up}|$, where $b_{up}$ is the upper bound of the sequence and the same argument here too. we can make this term as small as we want. The same goes to the absolute value of the third term on the right side of the identity. Finally $|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q} {a_{n}b_{n}}|<=|\sum\limits_{n=p}^{q-1} {s_{n}(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}|+|s_{q}b_{q}|+|s_{p-1}b_{p}|$. We can find $p$ and $q$ to make the right side small enough, completing the proof. Is this right? I am not satisfied what I have written here, I should have stated better in my opinion but the general idea of the proof is shown I suppose.

Comment: yeah, "making as small as we want" is a bad idea, but I can say that I can bound that sum by taking appropriate $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $\{b_n\}$ is increasing. If $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^n (s_k-s_{k-1})b_k=\sum_{k=1}^n s_kb_k-\sum_{k=2}^n s_{k-1}b_k=s_nb_n+
\sum_{k=2}^{n}s_{k-1}(b_{k-1}-b_{k}).
$$
Now $\{s_nb_n\}$ is convergent, as a product of convergent sequences, while the series
$\sum s_{n-1}(b_{n-1}-b_{n})$
is dominated by the series $\sum M(b_{n}-b_{n-1})$, where $M=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|s_n|$, and since $\{b_{n}-b_{n-1}\}$ is absolutely summable, 
so is  $\sum s_{n-1}(b_{n-1}-b_{n})$.

Comment: yeah, it looks like a similar idea, stated brilliantly.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is correct. The expression “the upper bound of the sequence” is not appropriate (there are infinitely many upper bounds). I think that it would be better to say that $b_{up}$ is *an* upper bound of the sequence $\bigl(\lvert b_n\rvert\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. With this choice, $b_{up}$ is non-negative. Also, with this choice you have$$\left\lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1}s_n(b_n-b_{n-1})\right\rvert\leqslant2\left\lvert\sum_{n=p}^{q-1}s_n\right\rvert b_{up}.$$Again, the expression “the difference of upper and lower bound of the sequence $b_n$” is not appropriate.

Comment: yeah, understood. Thanks for the response. By the way, saying that "we can make it as small as we want" is incorrect right? It would be more correct to say "bounded". Then the whole sum becomes "bounded" and not "as small as I wanted".

Comment: Oops! You are right. What you shoud use at that point is that $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a boounded sequence and that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lvert b_n-b_{n+1}\rvert$ converges (this follows from the fact that $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a monotonic and bounded sequence).

Comment: By the way, is it necessary for $b_{n}$ to be monotonic? cause I haven't used that fact, I just used the boundedness.

Comment: See my previous comment. Without that sequence being monotonic, how do you know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lvert b_n-b_{n+1}\rvert$ converges?

Comment: yes, I see. It was my bad. Thanks :)